# Intranet NT logged user

Tags: asp-classic, server-variables, request.servervariables

I have a welcome head

```
<h2>welcome</h2>
```

But I pretend get welcome to the NT logged user

this

```
<h2>Welcome <%response.write request.servervariables("LOGON_USER")%></h2>
```

gives me the `DOMAIN\USER`
how I can only show the user?
I don't want the domain appears in the text.

**EDITED:**

I edit this post to not create a new one.
I try google but can't find any help
I'm getting the correct NT-Logged user. However could I get the name of the nt-user... the corresponding one? Example: Mine NT-User is KFHM. but my name in windows is KikoFHM. At the moment I'm getting the KFHM but how to get the KikoFHM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Split()` to separate the Domain from the Username, it uses the `\` as a delimiter creating an Array with two elements, to get just the Username call the  second element.

```vb
Dim username

username = Split(Request.Servervariables("LOGON_USER"), "\")(1)
```

This is a quick and dirty approach you can expand it and check for the `\` beforehand to avoid errors, something like

```vb
Dim cred, domain, username,
cred = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") & ""
If InStr(1, cred, "\") > 0 Then
  cred = Split(cred, "\")
  domain = cred(0)
  username = cred(1)
End If
```

---

If [you not interested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369570/intranet-nt-logged-user/33369853?noredirect=1#comment54534879_33369853) in structuring your code at all you can always use this quick and dirty piece of code;

```vb
<%= Split(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") & "", "\")(1) %>
```

Comment: sry I add this 
`<div class="page-header">
        <% dim username = split (request.servervariables("LOGON_USER"), "\") (1)%>
            <h3>Wecolme<% dim username %></h3>
        </div>`
but gives me error... sry for be noob @Lankymart

Comment: @KikoFHM If this is Classic ASP you can't do syntax like `<% Dim username = .... %>` it won't work, you need to break the `Dim username` on to a separate line or use this little hack `Dim username : username = Split(request.servervariables("LOGON_USER"), "\") (1)%>`.

Comment: @KikoFHM If you want the quickest dirtiest way of doing this just use `<h2>Welcome <%= Split(Request.Servervariables("LOGON_USER") & "", "\")(1) %></h2>`

Comment: The quick and the dirty! +1!  ;o)

Comment: @Lankymart you help me before maybe you can help me now again... please see the edited post. yhanks

Comment: @KikoFHM You should really post a new question or Google, rather then modifying this one.